# query for get inactive users

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I Got stuck with the query. Here is my scenario.
I have two tables one is User and another is Transaction.

User table

```
Id   Name    Email
1    user1   user1@example.com
2    user2   user2@example.com
3    user3   user3@example.com
4    user4   user4@example.com
5    user5   user5@example.com
```

Transaction table

```
Id   UserId   Credit   Debit   Description      DateAdded
1    1        10.00     0.00   Add-Cash         2020-05-19 00:00:00.000
2    2         0.00    15.00   Buy Course XYZ   2020-04-01 00:00:00.000
3    3         0.00    20.00   Buy Course ABC   2020-05-15 00:00:00.000
4    4         0.00    15.00   Buy Course IJK   2020-05-01 00:00:00.000
```

I need to get the list of users who haven't bought any course from the last 30 days. So I need to use where clause in the query. I used where clause but didn't get the expected result.

Below is my expected output.

```
Id   Name    Email
1    user1   user1@example.com
2    user2   user2@example.com
5    user5   user5@example.com
```

Here is what I'm doing to get the output

```
SELECT U.Id, U.Name, U.Email FROM [User] U
LEFT JOIN [Transaction] T ON U.Id=T.UserId
WHERE T.Description LIKE '%Buy Course%'
GROUP BY U.Id, U.Name, U.Email
HAVING MAX(T.DateAdded) <= (GETDATE()-30)
```

Below is the script for tables

```
create database Test
use Test
create table [User]
(
   [Id] int,
   [Name] nvarchar(50),
   [Email] nvarchar(50)
)

create table [Transaction]
(
   [Id] int,
   [UserId] int,
   [Credit] decimal(18,2),
   [Debit] decimal(18,2),
   [Description] nvarchar(100),
   [DateAdded] datetime
)

insert into [User](Id, Name, Email) values(1,'user1','user1@example.com');
insert into [User](Id, Name, Email) values(2,'user2','user2@example.com');
insert into [User](Id, Name, Email) values(3,'user3','user3@example.com');
insert into [User](Id, Name, Email) values(4,'user4','user4@example.com');
insert into [User](Id, Name, Email) values(5,'user5','user5@example.com');

insert into [Transaction](Id, UserId, Credit, Debit, Description, DateAdded) values(1, 1, 10.00, 0.00, 'Add-Cash', '2020-05-19 00:00:00.000');
insert into [Transaction](Id, UserId, Credit, Debit, Description, DateAdded) values(2, 2, 0.00, 15.00, 'Buy Course XYZ', '2020-04-01 00:00:00.000');
insert into [Transaction](Id, UserId, Credit, Debit, Description, DateAdded) values(3, 3, 0.00, 20.00, 'Buy Course ABC', '2020-05-15 00:00:00.000');
insert into [Transaction](Id, UserId, Credit, Debit, Description, DateAdded) values(4, 4, 0.00, 15.00, 'Buy Course IJK', '2020-05-01 00:00:00.000');
```

Comment: Transaction 4 has a typo - "But course", not "Buy course".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to get the list of users who haven't bought any course from the last 30 days. So I need to use where clause in the query.

It is unclear what "bought any course" means in your data. Presumably it is related to the `where` clause in the query.

The basic idea is `not exists`:

```
select u.*
from users u
where not exists (select 1
                  from transactions t
                  where t.userid = u.id and and
                        t.Description like '%Buy Course%' and
                        t.dateadded > dateadd(day, -30, getdate())
                 );
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8458093c75995807677d485145906429) is a db<>fiddle.  Note that it changes the table names to `users` and `transactions` so they do not conflict with SQL Server reserved words.

You can modify a `where` clause in the subquery if your definition of "bought a course" is different.

Comment: This lacks the "bought a course" clause, which in the OP is handled via a string comparison (and the data has a typo).

Answer (score 1):

You can use not exists or a left join and check in join for nulls -- like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.id, users.name, users.email
FROM USERS
LEFT JOIN TRANSACTIONS AS T ON USERS.ID = T.USERID 
       AND T.Description LIKE 'Buy Course%'
       AND T.DateAdded >= DATEADD(day,-30, GETDATE())
WHERE T.USERID IS NULL
```

Here we join items you want to exclude and then take all the rows that are not joined.  I'm using the criteria you posted.